# Can someone please point me out what am i missing in the program below

Tags: android

I'm trying to pass context from one class to another.. pls tell me wat am i doing wrong..

**Draw.java**

```
public class Draw extends View{ 

    private Context context;
    private Paint paint = null;
    private Point start,end;
    public Draw(Context check){
        super(check);
        paint();
    }       

    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        canvas.drawRect(60,60,120,120,paint);
        Check check = new Check(context.getApplicationContext());
        check.update();
    }
    public void paint(){
        paint= new Paint();     
        paint.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
    }
}
```

**Check.java**

```
public class Check {
    private static Check check = null;
    private Context context;
    public Check(Context context){
        this.context = context;
    }

    void update() {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Context Received", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

**RectangleActivity.java**

```
public class RectangleActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Context context;
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Draw draw = new Draw(this);
        setContentView(draw);
    }
}
```

please help me.. I'm stuck with this problem for days...

Comment: what the problem you getting any error then please paste the error here from your logcat

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in your Draw-constructor, you never save the context to your variable, it should be like in the Check-constructor:

```
this.context = context;
```

otherwise you will have a `null` when you get to

```
context.getApplicationContext()
```

Which is also a bit unnecessary, it is enough to pass the `context` as it is.

Comment: You are welcome. Please mark the answer as the solution by clicking the little v-symbol to the left of it so people know that the question has been solved :)

Answer (score 1):

either initialize context variable in constructor. or use this.getContext(); instead of context in the view class.